# How to remove table breaking from puppeteer pdf

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

[image: Table break because of Page Break]

I'm generating a pdf using node js and puppeteer. I'm facing the issue of table break in my pdf because of page length and table length.

If there is any possible way to avoid this issue please help

```
 const { params } = request.body;
     
      const GENERATE_UUID = uuidv4();

      const path = `generated/letter_list_${GENERATE_UUID}.pdf`;

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ["--headless"],
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setContent(letter_list.parsed_html_string, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle0",
      });
      await page.addStyleTag({
      content: `
        @page {
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .date-time,.pageNumber,.title{
          display: none !important;
        }
      `,
    });
      await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
      await page.pdf({
        path: path,
        margin: { top: "180px", bottom: "100px", left: "30px", right: "30px" },
        printBackground: true,
        format: "A4",
      });
      await browser.close();
```

Comment: @KJ Thank you for the response. But it would be better if you could provide some code.

Comment: One possible approach, try to create a full screenshot and then convert it to a PDF file.

Comment: @xgqfrms Ok let me check if this approach will work for us. Thanks for the response.